# .NET Remoting migrating from 2.0 to 4.0 .NET version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, remoting, migrate

Stuck with a legacy web app that has its entire Biz & Data logic inside a .NET Remoting project.

Web project runs in 4.0, however Remoting layer is under 2.0.

Trying to see if its possible to migrate those DLL's to .NET 4.0 to simplify deployment process and remove the need to have 2 separate application pools.

Is this possible ?

According MSDN "legacy technology that is retained for backward compatibility with existing applications and is not recommended for new development." - so I'm assuming the namespaces should still be present in 4.0.

Comment: You should check the Remoting namespaces on MSDN to see if they're still available.  However, as of 3.0 WCF was the replacement for .NET Remoting and legacy (ASMX) web services.

Comment: Why haven't you tried it in the five minutes since you wrote this post?

Comment: Reputation? (joking..) Codebase wasn't available to me at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The remoting stuff still works fine in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thanks my MSDN reading supports the same. Will be running conversion in the morning.